# How can I get later and/or cron to only activate my function one time?

Tags: javascript, laterjs

I'm writing a code in Javascript. I've tried using different libraries to schedule events, including node-cron, node-schedule, and later. Scheduling events works just fine, but for some reason, it executes my function several times instead of just once. Sometimes it does it twice, sometimes 4 times. Sometimes it does it 10+ times before it moves on. I must be using this incorrectly somehow, but I don't see what's going wrong.

For context, this bit of code exists in a discord.js bot. Here's the code involved in the scheduling functions, using the later library. Currently, this works, just...it works way too many times. I only want it to execute my function one time.

```
var later = require("later");

var sched = later.parse.text('every 2 mins on the 30th sec');

function logTest() {
    console.log(`Please only do this once.`);
}

var timer = later.setTimeout(logTest, sched)
```

Comment: So you write "do that `every 2 minutes`" and are wondering why the library does what you ask it for?

Comment: I want it to do it once every two minutes, not several times every two minutes. I thought I had explained that well enough, I guess not.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question. So it seems that the problem is not in the scope of the code you posted. Perhaps there are multiple instances of your bot running?

Comment: That's one of the things I checked for, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the case. I can post more of the code if that would be helpful.

Comment: Either way, thank you so much for your response here. Now I at least know to stop looking here, and I can try to find something weird going on elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

My bot code used to look like this:

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var bot = new Discord.Client({ autoReconnect: true });
var later = require("later");

bot.on("message", msg => {

.......

var sched = later.parse.text('every 2 mins on the 30th sec');

function logTest() {
    console.log(`Please only do this once.`);
}

var timer = later.setTimeout(logTest, sched)

.....
});
```

Now it looks like this:

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var bot = new Discord.Client({ autoReconnect: true });
var later = require("later");

var sched = later.parse.text('every 2 mins on the 30th sec');

function logTest() {
    console.log(`Please only do this once.`);
}

var timer = later.setTimeout(logTest, sched)

.....

bot.on("message", msg => {

.......


.....
});
```

The second code here works. My "later" code needed to be outside of the messaging block, which was interfering with it. Thanks Patrick for leading me in the right direction!